# When working on a Intellij plugin, how do you configure the "Plugin" run configuration in Intellij Idea CE to enable auto reload?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build.gradle, intellij-plugin

I've been looking at developing an Intellij platform plugin and saw the docs mentioned [auto reloading of plugins by adding the system property `idea.auto.reload.plugins` to the `runIde` Gradle task](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/ide_development_instance.html?search=Log#enabling-auto-reload)

How can I edit the run configuration to set this property? [image]

Comment: That property is for reloading IDE dynamic plugins (enabling/disabling plugin without IDE restart). If you want your source code to be hot-swapped, see the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | HotSwap | **Reload classes after compilation** options.

Comment: Note that this setting is true by default  https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/commit/a2cad53c44dc713a17dbe11ef0dee3a9c61edfb1